# Who sells jewelry?

Tags: diablo-iii

Covetous Shen seems obsessed with gems but not the other sparkly fashion accessories that make my character absolutely *fabulous*, so I can't rely on him for a minimum upgrade for amulets and rings.  The vendor in the north of New Tristam sold me my first pair of rings, but I'm in act III and I don't know where to look to try to upgrade my very dated rings and amulet.

Who and where are vendors that sell rings and amulets in each act?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Diablo III has a handful of merchants, but for the most part, they are named for your convenience. Specifically, only merchants known as, "... the Fence" will sell you "Trinkets", which include both amulets and rings. They will show up on your minimap as "Fence".

### Act I: Radek the Fence

Radek the Fence is in the Nortwest part of Tristram, on your way towards the Northwest gate.

[image]

### Act II: Silmak the Fence

Silmak is also chilling in the Northwestern part of the town, though in his case, he's overlooking the city, a little east of the healer.

[image]

### Act III & IV: Litton the Fence

Litton is hiding in the southmost part of the Worldstone Keep area, where he will sell you the belongings of dead soldiers.

[image]

Comment: Yay, pics :P  Was the Act III guy not immediately available?  I found him a little while after my post; I don't think I'm that blind

Comment: @NickT I've yet to complete any quests in Act III (I'm on "Light the Signal Fires") so... no? You really are that blind. ;)

Comment: I *seem* to remember a couple of merchants that sold jewelry who were **not** in a town.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I believe those are random encounters, but that's beyond the scope of the question. (Nick specifies in the town)

Comment: Additional info never hurts :(

Comment: Because of the way the story goes, the Act 3 town is also used in Act 4.

Comment: @Albort Ah, yes. I had verified that for myself, but thanks for reminding me to update this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Any vendor that is a Fence (seller of stolen goods) will sell jewelry.